# Regex - How to get value for multiple cases with/without brackets?

Tags: java, regex

I have these two inputs:

- "time":"123456789"}value=xxxxxx,
- "time":123456789,

I need to get the `123456789` value using **regex**, currently my pattern is as follows:

```
String ps = "time:\\"(.*)\\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ps);
```

And this is not enough for both cases, how can I have it for both of them please?

I can have this solution using only regexes over `Java`

Comment: `\d+` matches the number in both cases. Can you be more specific why this would not meet your requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"time\":\"?(\\d+)");
```

and use captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tS3kQ7/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/\"?\d+/gm
```

That will select only numbers!

https://regex101.com/r/nB9eT1/1